# AdView and layout. I can't run ads in Libgdx Android app

Tags: java, android-layout, libgdx, ads

TapForTap's code looks easy for simple Android app:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
```

ad_view is defined in XML:

```
    <com.tapfortap.AdView android:id="@+id/ad_view"
                      android:layout_height="50dip"
                      android:layout_width="320dip"
                      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                      />
```

But I use Libgdx and I need something like that:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGame(), false); //this runs Libgdx
    MobclixAdView adView = new MobclixMMABannerXLAdView(this);
    adView.getAd();
    adView.setRefreshTime(30000);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    layout.addView(gameView);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
    setContentView(layout);
```

The problem is that TapForTap's AdView has not constructor,
so I can't write:

```
AdView adview=new AdView();
```

If I do

```
layout.addView(adView);
```

I got an error that adView already has parent.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For using an AdView you need some changes to your Android projekt. Take a look at this entry of the wiki from libgdx. It has a compleat solution for using an AdView. You should be able to convert your into that solution.

[Wiki entry for admob in libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx)
regards

Comment: I have integrated Admob to my Libgdx Android code. But I can't integrate tapForTap because their code is based on main.xml. I don't know how to add "AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);" to my layout. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first attach View to Layout. For example -

```
fullAdView = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ad_full, null);
```

Have a look for more at this link.

http://www.ikergarcia.com/en/juego-android-libgdx-admob/